# Telegram games bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to build a telegram bot to play games for my son.
Basically, I want to get a response from the bot by using a command handler.
when I request a command handler it should give me a random response from 2 different lists.

The game is predicting food dish name like "apple pie", apple will be in list 1 and pie will be in list 2
and the bot should get different values from the list and give a response as one message via command handler.

Will appreciate your guidance/help

Below is the python code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram import error, update
import sys
import os
import random

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hello, play games!')


def shuffle2d(arr2d, rand_list=random):
    """Shuffes entries of 2-d array arr2d, preserving shape."""
    reshape = []
    data = []
    iend = 0
    for row in arr2d:
        data.extend(row)
        istart, iend = iend, iend+len(row)
        reshape.append((istart, iend))
        rand_list.shuffle(data)
    return [data[istart:iend] for (istart,iend) in reshape]

def show(arr2d):
    """Shows rows of matrix (of strings) as space-separated rows."""
    show ("\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in arr2d))
    A = A.rand_list['APPLE, PUMKIN, STRAWBERRY, BANANA,CHOCOLATE']
    B = B.rand_list['PIE, ICE-CREAM, CAKE,SHAKE'] 
    arr2d = []
    arr2d.append([A+(j) for j in range(1,B+1)])
    show(shuffle2d(arr2d))
    print(show)
    return show

def play(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /play is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text(shuffle2d)

def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("1XXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXY", use_context=True)


    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("play", play))


    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, play))


    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You've just leaked the http api token `1229001418:AAEHMsihwI2dFSavL7m12yMkIk5MrqqRquA`, which means that anyone can now send and receive messages through your bot's profile. I'd suggest you create another one, and keep your tokens secret from now on ;)

Comment: Sure LukaSaS...Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example of how is the interaction with your bot? That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you @SergioR for your response, Basically, I want to send command (/play) to my bot and that will choose random dishes from two different lists and should throw a single output. like Banana Shake - banana from 1st list and shake from 2nd list but the output should be random everytime I send the /play command to my bot.

Lists - 
A list  - ['APPLE, PUMKIN, STRAWBERRY, BANANA,CHOCOLATE']
B  list - ['PIE, ICE-CREAM, CAKE,SHAKE']

Comment: So you send /play, the bot answer with two words (randomly selected from two separated lists) and then? you send /play again so the bot answer with two new random words?

Comment: yes, you are right, the bot will send random answers every time I send /play command and the bot will select the random answers from the list everytime with new results. Thanks again @SergioR for helping me with this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code you use a function called `shuffleDish()` that creates a string containing two random words chosen from separated list and it's called from the commandhandler "play"

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from telegram import error, update
import random
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def shuffleDish():
    A = ['APPLE', 'PUMKIN', 'STRAWBERRY', 'BANANA', 'CHOCOLATE']
    B = ['PIE', 'ICE-CREAM', 'CAKE', 'SHAKE']
    dish = random.choice(A)+" "+random.choice(B)
    return dish

def play(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(shuffleDish())

def error(update, context):
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)

def main():
    updater = Updater(tgtoken, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("play", play))
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @SergioR you been of great help..Now I can play games with my son :) Thanks again